# Why do I have a plethora of mysqld instances running?

Tags: 22.04, mysql

I am running Ubuntu 22.04, which I recently installed from scratch.  I use eclipse, apache2 primarily,  browser.  For the past few days, eclipse runs out of memory and halts.
[image]
When investigating, I discovered 30+ instances of mysqld running. I cannot filter a mysqld instance using `ps aux` but I can observe them using `htop` (see image).

30 instances seems out of order to me. Why should there be so many instances?

Comment: Please provide some output from `top`, `htop` or similar. Is it child processes/threads? This wouldn't surprise me.

Comment: FYI, I have a MariaDB instance that hardly does anything, and it has 10 userland child processes in `htop` (green colored).

Comment: They're threads, it's fine, working as designed. `htop` breaks threads out in the list, `ps` doesn't.

Comment: I always hide "Userland" processes in `htop`, since they mostly distract more than they inform.

Comment: Thanks for all the insight.  After following the link that @popey shared, I discovered that, indeed, all but 1 (we'll call it process) is a thread and htop shows them as children of the process.